# How do I disconnect my Hotmail account from my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, account-management

I have separate Hotmail and Gmail accounts. A friend has been emailing me from his Gmail account, to my Hotmail account, and he has been able to view my Gmail account and Gmail account photograph. Although my Hotmail account doesn't have an image uploaded, he can see the photo connected to my Gmail account when we exchange emails, and my name comes up as it is on Gmail.

I have looked through all options on both accounts - but haven't found any mention of either email addresses on both. I can't remember if I linked the account somehow from Gmail, as I have had Hotmail for a very long time and Gmail only perhaps for a year or two. I have tried to disconnect them, as I don't want any links to other accounts from my Hotmail account and those who email me there.

From Hotmail, I have already tried 'manage other accounts' and 'remove alias' but there are no other email accounts connected to my Hotmail account. I cannot locate any reference to my Gmail account in any field on Outlook. Really annoying, as obviously Gmail is connected somehow to my Hotmail, but I cannot see how.

Comment: Your friend probably has both of your addresses in his/her Google Contacts.

Answer (score 1):

The connection has been made inside your friend's Contacts list.  Because your friend has somehow  got your gmail address as well as your hotmail address, and s/he had said that they belong to the same person, the connection is made - but ONLY inside his/her contacts.    The only way to break it is to ask your friend to delete the gmail address and profile picture for you from his/her contacts.

In future, do not tell your gmail address to anyone who you want to use your Hotmail address.